# Zero-padding with glue

Tags: r, r-glue

I want to use `glue` to accomplish `sprintf('%02d', x)` but I'm not sure it's possible.

`vignette('transformers')` suggests a `sprintf`-alike transformer `sprintf_transformer` and "front end" wrapper `glue_fmt` like this:

```
sprintf_transformer <- function(text, envir) {
  m <- regexpr(":.+$", text)
  if (m != -1) {
    format <- substring(regmatches(text, m), 2)
    regmatches(text, m) <- ""
    res <- eval(parse(text = text, keep.source = FALSE), envir)
    do.call(sprintf, list(glue("%{format}f"), res))
  } else {
    eval(parse(text = text, keep.source = FALSE), envir)
  }
}

glue_fmt <- function(..., .envir = parent.frame()) {
  glue(..., .transformer = sprintf_transformer, .envir = .envir)
}
```

Then gives a simple example:

```
glue_fmt("π = {pi:.2}")
#> π = 3.14
```

This seems to rely on lazy evaluation to split the call `pi:.2` (which is valid R syntax) into a call to `sprintf`: `sprintf('%.2f', pi)`.

However it would appear to me this isn't possible for the case of 0-padding, since the R parser will eliminate any leading 0:

```
pid = as.integer(pi)
glue_fmt('{pid:02}')
# 3.000000
# vs desired
sprintf('%02d', pid)
# [1] "03"
```

Looking at `sprintf_transformer`, `f` is hard-coded, because `02d` and `.2f` are not valid R syntax in and of themselves. I guess we could make `glue_fmtd` and `glue_fmtf` or add an argument to supply `'d'` or `'f'`, but this is already straining the convenience factor of `glue_fmt` compared to plain `sprintf`.

And this would still not get over the fundamental constraint of the R parser -- as soon as `02` is treated as R code, the parser will drop the leading 0.

So, I'm stuck -- is it possible to use `glue` to do a zero-padded format in a way that's not overly convoluted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need valid R syntax in the transfomer. The string is processed as a string. You don't need to hardcore the f or d. For example if you have

```
sprintf_transformer <- function(text, envir) {
  m <- regexpr(":.+$", text)
  if (m != -1) {
    format <- substring(regmatches(text, m), 2)
    regmatches(text, m) <- ""
    res <- eval(parse(text = text, keep.source = FALSE), envir)
    do.call(sprintf, list(glue("%{format}"), res))
  } else {
    eval(parse(text = text, keep.source = FALSE), envir)
  }
}
```

Then you can do

```
glue_fmt('{pid:02d}')
# 03
glue_fmt('{pid:0.02f}')
# 3.00
```